# Merge tags: [persistence] and [persistent-storage]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistence), [persistent-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent-storage) *sound* like they could be different; but not according to the tag-wikis:

Persistence:

> Persistence in computer programming refers to the capability of saving data outside the application memory.

- [Saved video in iOS is lost during updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588707/saved-video-in-ios-is-lost-during-updates)
- [How to make an object persist after a loop in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575735/how-to-make-an-object-persist-after-a-loop-in-scala)
- [hibernate validation doesn't happen on persist in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336846/hibernate-validation-doesnt-happen-on-persist-in-database)
- [Java persistence - No parrent key found after flushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102919/java-persistence-no-parrent-key-found-after-flushing)

Persistent-storage:

> The persistent storage describes a mechanism, that preserves the value of a variable over the lifetime of the executed script or program.

- [Delete unused persistent data without reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891302/delete-unused-persistent-data-without-reference)
- [Best practices for storing translatable android strings in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088429/best-practices-for-storing-translatable-android-strings-in-db)
- [Why use normal attributes (attribute.set[..]) in chef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560474/why-use-normal-attributes-attribute-set-in-chef)
- [VB 2013 Persistent User Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518340/vb-2013-persistent-user-settings)

I think if the intention is to refer to persistent *state* and *data* respectively, (which doesn't seem to be reflected by the questions) that the wikis could be improved. Otherwise, this is a [synonym-request].

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the questions

- 3,366 Tagged [persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistence) with 50 follower
- 199 Tagged [persistent-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent-storage) with 1 follower
- of these 11 are [tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistence+persistent-storage)

Also the wiki description of persistent-storage is contrary to the concept.  If the variable only exists during the execution of script or program it is not persistent.

I would think a re-tag [persistent-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent-storage) to [persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistence) or remove [persistent-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent-storage) if both.  And let [persistent-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent-storage) burn.